# How can I show a DIV when hovering on a DIV using pure CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

this is my fiddle with html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/v2r5we0r/

I'm trying to show a DIV "station_info"(shape of a square) when either clicked/hovered on those DIVs "boxes" right next to it (it will have information from my database table that I will put later on).

I have my PHP posted since I'm looping through my DB to create those boxes.

Is it possible using only CSS and HTML? If so, how can i? I only find examples with Jquery, I don't want to use JQuery or Javascript.

**Scroll down** the Result in fiddle to see the smalss boxes

Thank you in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
 <div id="map_size" align="center">


<div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:20px;top:1230px;'>id:84
 <div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>
</div> <!-- end div map_Size -->
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*body*/
body{
margin:0px auto;
width:80%;
height:80%;   
}

/*map size*/
#map_size{
width:1190px;
height:1300px;
background:#0099FF;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
position: relative;
}

 /* desk boxes*/
.desk_box{ 
width: 23px;
height: 10px;
border: 4px solid black; 
padding:10px;
}   
.desk_box > .station_info{
display:none;
}
.desk_box > .station_info:first-child{
display:block;
}
.desk_box > div:hover + div {
display: block; 
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';

//query to get X,Y coordinates from DB
$coord_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates";
$coord_result = mysqli_query($conn,$coord_sql);

//see if query is good
if($coord_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}
?>
<div id="map_size" align="center">

                <?php
            //get number of rows for X,Y coords in the table
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($coord_result)){    
                        //naming X,Y values
                        $x_id = $row['coordinate_id'];
                        $x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
                        $y_pos = $row['y_coord'];

                    //draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
                echo "<div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>id:".$x_id."<div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>";
                } //end while coord_result loop
                ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need the output HTML & possibly CSS

Comment: its in my jsfiddle...

Comment: Unfortunately, if the fiddle went away your code would not be useful to others. a *minimal** amount of HTML would be useful in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS can only work descending or going further in the same level in the DOM tree, so you'll have to put the div you wanna hide/show on hover AFTER all the DIVs you're going to hover. Then you can use the general sibling operator: `~` which looks for elements AFTER a given element.

Say you have

```
.toto ~ .titi {}
```

then those `<div class="titi">` will match

```
<div class="toto"><div>
<div class="titi"></div>
```

Or

```
<div class="toto"></div>
<div class="whatever"></div>
<div class="titi"></div>
```

But this one won't

```
<div class="titi"></div>
<div class="toto"></div>
```

Here's a snippet to see if this is what you want.

```css
/*body*/
body{
 margin:0px auto;
 width:80%;
 height:80%;
}

/*map size*/
#map_size{
 width:1190px;
 height:1300px;
 background:#0099FF;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 position: relative;
 }

/* desk boxes*/
.desk_box{ 
 width: 23px;
 height: 10px;
 border: 4px solid black; 
 padding:10px;
 } 
.desk_box > .station_info{
 display:none;
}
.desk_box > .station_info:first-child{
 display:block;
}
.desk_box > div:hover + div {
    display: block
}

.div-to-show {
    display: none;
}
.desk_box:hover ~ .div-to-show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_size" align="center">
    <div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:20px;top:1230px;'>id:84<div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>
    <div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:20px;top:1165px;'>id:85<div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>
    <div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:20px;top:1100px;'>id:86<div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>
    <div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:20px;top:1035px;'>id:87<div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>
    <div class='desk_box' style='position:absolute;left:73px;top:1230px;'>id:92<div class='station_info'>Hello</div></div>
    
    <div class="div-to-show" style="position: absolute; left:150px; bottom: 100px;">Oh hi !</div>
</div> <!-- end div map_Size -->
```

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted but now I'm having problems since I need to create it for each of the "desk_box" DIVs, when I hover over one it's displaying all of them instead of showing up individually.

Comment: Then you can use the direct sibling operator: `+`, but you'll have to put the hovered element and its target element together by groups of 2 so the target element is directly after its hovered element. I'm not sure I'm clear enough.